# BarButtonItem crashing ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble with a bar button item in my view did load method. I have a subview thats being added to a superview and when i click the barbuttonitem it crashes the app and i get this error

```
*** -[DetailViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x27677fa0


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    navBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIColor *topGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.f green:241/255.f blue:206/255.f alpha:1];
    UIColor *bottomGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:242/255.f green:237/255.f blue:204/255.f alpha:1];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topGreen.CGColor, (id)bottomGreen.CGColor, nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(returnToMap:)];
    UINavigationItem *navButton = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init];
    navButton.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:navButton animated:YES];
    navBar.topItem.title = title;
    NSLog(@"Reached");
    //[self returnToMap];
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. i've tried added the barbutton as a property and synting it but nothing seems to work. any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the `UIBarButtonItem`, but in `DetailViewController` instance- you are releasing it too early, or not keeping the reference.

Comment: ARC should take care of that shouldn't it?

Comment: actually, ARC might be causing the issue. It might get lost in your code and assume that `DetailViewController` is not needed any more.  Could you add the implementation of the `returnToMap:` (the method app crashes in after the button tap) method to your question?